How to find the LCP of a react app using playwright with typescript?
Need to get the Largest Contentful paint of a react app using playwright with typescript
This is for web performance testing and should be the exact value
I tried https://web.dev/articles/lcp#measure-lcp-in-javascript and implemented the same using Typescript
But we need to know, if we have something else, I feel this value is different from the value what get after checking in the performance tab
 return page.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise<PerformancePaintTiming>((resolve) => {
      new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
        const lcpEntry = entryList.getEntries().find(entry => entry.entryType === 'largest-contentful-paint');
        if (lcpEntry) resolve(lcpEntry as PerformancePaintTiming);
      }).observe({ type: 'largest-contentful-paint', buffered: true });
    });
  });


Please [edit] your post. Big code dumps don't work well in comments. What's the problem with your current code exactly? What value were you expecting and what are you getting?

I don't understand the question. What do you mean "But we need to know, if we have something else"? Are you asking when the final LCP can be known and when you can be sure no further LCPs will come in?

I have compared the actual performance, by clicking the performance button record button and the same via the code. But the code seems to have a higher response time

Each time you run the performance report or via the code, the values of the performance metrics will be different. It will mostly not fluctuate a lot but shall fall in the same range like poor, average or good. Each time you load the page, something will be different - like an external resource might stall, your CPU might be prioritising other programs, not enough RAM, browser extensions interfering... So we cannot expect the same values of the performance metrics for each run.

If you want a more stable (and more real) value you may have to monitor the RUM data which is usually an average value of past ~30 days collected from real users. It will not fluctuate for every successive run, but it will change over time - few weeks or months, as it is an average of previous 30 days. So you will know if the previous deployments have impacted your site performance.

Im planning to add these tests as a part of the pipeline and if that success then only we can merge the code. Is there any way to do programmatically?
